# codeigniter global instance of model

Tags: php, codeigniter, instance

This is a [seemingly] simple question and I'm hoping I get a quick answer as my afternoon depends on the answer :D

In Codeigniter, if I create a named instance of a model in another model, what is the scope of the new object?

hope this clarifies a bit more:

If in 'user_model' I create an instance of 'logging_model' thus:

```
$this->load->model('logging_model', 'logging');
```

if in 'post_model' I need access to the new 'logging' instance created in the user model, do I just call the same piece of code in the constructor/function that I need to have access?

so if user_model sets an attribute of $this->logging->posts = 0;

I want post_model to access the 'posts' attribute with the newly set value, would just by instantiating the logging_model with the same instance name (logging) inside posts_model give access to the object created by user_model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*do I just call the same piece of code in the constructor/function that I need to have access?*

No - if you need the model in multiple places you should call it in `config/autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

To load a model you will require to write

```
$this->model->(your model name here)
```

To load globally you will require to call your model in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['model'] = array('your model1', 'your model2');
```

I hope this is helpful.